# ASCII encoding error while scraping data

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to scrape cell phones from a website. The format of the cell phone is like this

```
+971553453301‪
```

Here is the piece of code for the task

```
try:
    phone=soup.find("div", "phone-content")
    for a in phone:
        phone_result= str(a).get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
    print "Phone information:", phone_result
except StandardError as e:
    phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print phone_result
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u202a' in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help?

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: @PauloBu: isn't that clear from the `print` statements?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I don't know what I was thinking :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things awkward with this line of code:

```
phone_result= str(a).get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
```

First of all, `BeautifulSoup` works with unicode so in Python2 casting its text to `str` is error prone. There's where I think is the mistake because even if the cast work, you're calling `get_text()` to a `str` object which will raise `NameError`.

To end, you call `encode` to the `str` which in Python 2 is already encoded and it can potentially fail because Python 2 will decode it first (with a default encoding) and then encode it again.

So try with this fix assuming the web page is encoded in `utf8`:

```
phone_result= a.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
```

There is also a problem with this line:

```
phone=soup.find("div", "phone-content")
```

[`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=get_text#find) will just return a single result, a [`Tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=get_text#tag) object, you should better use [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=get_text#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) which will return a list of `Tag` objects. The difference is that when you iterate through the result of a single `Tag` object you'll get [`NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=get_text#navigablestring)s which doesn't have `get_text` method. When you iterate through a list of `Tag` objects you get `Tag` objects in your iteration which have the `get_text` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use str because i am using get_text() . if i use ur lihne of code with removing the str it gives this error NavigableString 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: @user3265370 Hmm, but In my opinion `str` nor `unicode` have the method `get_text` either.

Comment: @user3265370 Change `find` with `find_all` since `find` will only return a result. Can you try it?

Comment: perfect. it does solve the problem. how can the multiple results effect the asci code error, can u please explain?

Comment: @user3265370 I edited the answer, the problem is that `find` and `find_all` return different objects and the one returned by `find` doesn't have a `get_text` method.

Comment: @user3265370 Added a little more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing str(a) with unicode(a) and skip the .encode()

Comment: First, no need to `unicode(a)` because a.get_text() will return a `unicode` object. Second, this won't work `unicode(a).get_text()` because `unicode` doesn't have a `get_text()` method.

Comment: exactly @PauloBu it gives this eroor NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'